# Rails 5.1+: namespaced models and default path generators

Tags: routes, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using namespaces on my models to organize a large project. However, when you namespace a model, the default url/path generators in Rails use that namespace in the routes:

```
module Workflows
  class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
    # ...
  end
end

<%= form_with model: @workflow, url: @workflow do |form| %>
# => produces URL: workflows_workflow_path(@workflow)
```

I've seen lots of SO posts about overriding the `model_name` but it doesn't do anything for me.  I've tried all of the following versions:

```
module Workflows
  class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
    def self.model_name
      # Have tried all of the following as per various SO questions...
      ActiveModel::Name.new(Workflow)
      ActiveModel::Name.new(::Workflows::Workflow, nil, nil)
    end
  end
end
```

When I check the model_name, it specifically says that the `route_key` is `workflows_workflow`, even with the ActiveModel name overrides in place.

I'm running Rails 5.1 and Ruby 2.4.1.

How do I force Rails to treat these namespaced models as non-namespaced?  The namespacing is just for developer organization, I don't need Rails to "do" anything with the namespacing.

Comment: That's an odd problem. Don't know if it might be an issue, but try changing ```class Workflow < ApplicationRecord``` to  ```class Workflow < ApplicationRecord::Base```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
module Workflows
  class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
    def self.model_name
      ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Workflow")
    end
  end
end
```

Like specified [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1168).